# How to power 24v noctua fan?

Tags: power-supply, cooling, fan-controller

There exists 140mm computer fans: Noctua NF-A14 industrialPPC-24V-3000 IP67 PWM:
[image]
[image]

They are supposed to be powered from 24V to get full RPM. How in computer system it is supposed to power them with 24 volts? Where from should I get 24v? Should I buy additional power supply and or controller for them? What are that devices?

What should be "full pipeline" from outlet to the connector of such fan? And how motherboard can control it via PWM if its supposed to be connected to something else?

PS. I know that I can power them from 12v, also i know that there are 12v versions. I am asking about 24v versions usage

Comment: This line of fan products from Noctua seems like it is meant to be used in unusual cooling solutions where power is provided separately from the ATX PSU. Imagine a server rack with its own wiring for just the fans, or an industrial PC chassis that has power supply for other equipment like a PLC inside it. You will need a dedicated 24V power supply for this fan unless you want to do something risky with the PC power.

Comment: @Romen yep, can you please provide an examples of such 24v power supplies, to which i can connect this fan? anything - links or even just part numbers..

Comment: Any 24V DC power supply, you don't need any specific product. Just connect the yellow wire from the fan to + and the black wire to -. If you need to run a lot of fans this way then a power supply that has higher Amps output may be needed. There are far too many kinds of power supplies to narrow down what you need without giving more requirements.